# How do you set displayName dynamically with a higher order component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to set displayName dynamically because every component renders as `<Component ... />` and makes it impossible to debug. I've so far set `static displayName` on each component and it works fine, it's just a lot of repeated code.

Many components extend this component and as such result's in a hierarchy entirely of unnamed components. How could I save setting `static displayName` on each component that extends Component?

**root component**

```
export class Component extends React.Component {
  static component = 'span';
  static style = {
    base: {}
  };

  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    this.style = this.constructor.style;
    this.switches = this.constructor.switches;
    this.component = this.constructor.component;
    // this.displayName = this.constructor.displayName;
  }

  getRenderProps() {
    ...
    return props;
  }

  render() {
    return React.createElement(this.component, this.getRenderProps(), this.props.children);
  }
}
```

**other classes**

```
class SomeClass extends Component {
   ...
}
```

SomeClass now renders as `<Component>` unless explicitly setting `static displayName` on it resulting in:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by extends? Are other component defined as `class Foo extends Component` where `Component` is the one you've defined above?

Comment: I'm trying to think of an answer that works with this pattern, but I can't help to think that the pattern itself is not very good. You're not really using a higher order component so much as you are using prototype inheritance to achieve some kind of pseudo subclassing. A more typical higher order function that takes a component as an argument and passes props to it would better suit your situation and preserve the correct display name as well.

Comment: What are you looking for? `static displayName() { return this.name; }`? Please show us some examples of your "lots of repeated code".

Comment: @Bergi all the info is in my post, look at the screenshot

Comment: @eveo You said "*I've so far set static displayName on each component and it works fine*", I want to see that code. If you only refer to the commented line, that's not much code.

Comment: well i mean it's literally just `class SomeComp extends Component { static displayName = "name" }`

Comment: But what is "name"? If it's different everywhere, it's not repeated code. If it's the same, just inherit it from `Component`. So what do you want it to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const decorate = <P extends object>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<P>,
    displayName?:string
  ): React.FC<P> => ({
      ...props
  }: P) =>{
      const WithName = withStyles({})(Component as React.FC) 
      WithName.displayName = displayName
    return <WithName {...props as P} />
  }
```

And then use like this:

(Note! need to be outside a component)

```
const MyComp = decorate(Compo, "MyComp")
```

If someone found a cleaner way tag my name please